# How enable compression for a JSON REST call in Suave?

Tags: json, f#, gzip, suave

I want to know how return JSON for my REST calls compressed:

```
GET /orders HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

But the docs only talk about returning files

```
let setJson it =
    it
    |>JsonUtils.toJson
    |> OK
    >=> setMimeType "application/json; charset=utf-8"

let doReq route request action =
    path route >=> setCORSHeaders >=> request (fun r -> action(r) |> setJson)

doReq "/orders" request (fun r -> queryOrders(r |> getTerm, Products.Name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is configured in the MIME type maps by adding a new MIME type and passing `true` for the second parameter, like this:

```
let mimeTypes =
  defaultMimeTypesMap
    @@ (function | ".json" -> createMimeType "application/json" true | _ -> None)

let webConfig = { defaultConfig with mimeTypesMap = mimeTypes }
```

The configuration for MIME types and compression is documented on [this page](https://suave.io/files.html).

Comment: Are you sure?  I think the MIME type itself is what's used to determine whether to apply compression.  There is a `MIN_BYTES_TO_COMPRESS` of 500 that is applied in the `Compression.transform` function, so if your response is less than 500 bytes, it will never be compressed.

Comment: Oh, is that. MIN_BYTES_TO_COMPRESS